# PCap04 initialisation sequence

Tags: capacitor, spi, measurement

I'm developing SPI interface with a very complex and badly documented PCap04 device. I've already implemented and tested all commands, but the results are always very unstable. Even the charging/discharging of the capacitors were verified with oscilloscope.

I would like to measure floating and differential capacitors (max. 12 pF) connected to PC0-PC1 and PC2-PC3 where PC1 and PC2 are connected together and with a common point of sensor based on the differential capacitance.

The PCap04 includes ROM, SRAM, FLASH, and RAM and as software: firmware, configurations, and status registers, but also a few commands to manage SRAM and FLASH.

What is the right command sequence to initialize and measure the connected sensor?
I've previously erased the NVRAM and modified the low and high ID. Today my sequence is:

SPI_test, reset (power_On), download my configuration array including BitRun set, initialization and start CDC convertor controlled by CDC start command.

What is wrong? Why are the results always very unstable? Do I need to download firmware each time?

Comment: It seems that the problem is results reading. For example: RES0 is 32 bits read by four SPI 0x00 sending giving (0, 1, 2 and 3) bytes. If, I invert  all 32 bits done with 0,1,2,= and 3 bytes, the results seems to be correct. Could be possible? (I love PCap04)

Comment: The answer is in datasheet: figure 65.

Comment: Stuck with the same situation, can you share your firmware if you got it right?